# How to remove duplication from RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Here is my spec file:

```
context "answer is correct" do
    before(:each) do
      @answer = stub_model(Answer, :correct => true).as_new_record
      assigns[:answer] = @answer

      render "answers/summarize"
    end

    it "should display flashcard context properly" do
      response.should contain("Quiz")
    end

    it "should summarize results" do
      response.should contain("is correct")
    end
  end

  context "answer is incorrect" do
    before(:each) do
      @answer = stub_model(Answer, :correct => false).as_new_record
      assigns[:answer] = @answer

      render "answers/summarize"
    end

    it "should display flashcard context properly" do
      response.should contain("Quiz")
    end

    it "should summarize results" do
      response.should contain("is incorrect")
    end
  end
```

How do I avoid repeating the following block within both of the above contexts?

```
it "should display flashcard context properly" do
  response.should contain("Quiz")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to wrap up some of your tests, you can do it like this:

```
def answer_tests
  it "should display flashcard context properly" do
    response.should contain "Quiz"
  end

  it "should do be awesome" do
    response.should be_awesome
  end
end

context "answer is correct" do
  answer_tests

  it "should summarize results" do
    response.should contain "is correct"
  end
end

context "answer is incorrect" do
  answer_tests

  it "should summarize results" do
    response.should contain "is incorrect"
  end
end
```

As you can see, this is really handy when you have more than one test you want to wrap up in a method.

Answer (score 0):

Your specs describe the behavior you expect from your code - this amount of repetition is ok.

If it gets out of hand, use different contexts to isolate different expectations. For example, you could factor those duplicate expectations into a new context that just tests the page no matter what the Answer is.